# Bash - meaning of a simple question mark (?)

Tags: bash, shell, syntax, glob

I was playing around with some bash features and as I tried echo-ing some output, I noticed, that

```
echo what about in some more complex example ?
```

results in

> what about in some more complex example \

I know that escaping the question mark or the whole line with quotes resolves the problem, but I am curious of why is it happening.

So my 2 questions are:

1. What is the meaning of a simple question mark in bash (I know for example about the '$?' special parameter and regex usage) ?
2. I suppose that is is a bash environment variable or some king of variable. How can I inspect a variable ? For example a command can be inspected with **type** keyword, i.e.
   `type cd`

Comment: Odd: you have a file named ``\`` in your current directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that context it functions as a [glob](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) pattern. If there are files with one-character names in the current working directory, the shell expands an unquoted question mark to their names.

```
$ echo ? \? '?' "?"
? ? ? ?
$ touch a b c
$ echo ? \? '?' "?"
a b c ? ? ?
```

Similarly, `??` is expanded to two-character filenames, `??*` to filenames longer than one character, and `??[ab]` to three-character filenames ending with an **a** or a **b**, etc.

See [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion) for further information.